# Is it possible to know exactly how many views any question has got?

Tags: support, search, questions

It seems we can know exactly the number of views ONLY when that number is not greater than 949. From then on it will not show the exact number but instead will show 1k, 2k and so on.

For example, the question : [What is the mystery of ayOnija (अयोनिज) births?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9204/what-is-the-mystery-of-ayonija-%e0%a4%85%e0%a4%af%e0%a5%8b%e0%a4%a8%e0%a4%bf%e0%a4%9c-births) has 3k views.

[image]

So, it is just giving a range within which lies the exact number of views.

Where as, for this question: [What bodies (Koshas or layers) do Devas, Trimurthis and their Shaktis (consorts) have?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10118/what-bodies-koshas-or-layers-do-devas-trimurthis-and-their-shaktis-consorts) , we can know the exact number of views it has got viz - 227.

[image]

- So, my question is whether there is any method by which we can know the exact number of views any question has got?

Comment: Good question @Rickross

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hover over the '3k views' label to show the exact count:

[image]

Of course, if you're using a phone or tablet, hovering is rather difficult.

Comment: The answer is informative. Thanks.

Comment: On a phone, **if sometimes it's really necessary** I use https://www.view-page-source.com and enter the question URL. After that I use the browser's option `Find in page` and type `viewed`. The first result has the number of views. :)